# jQuery Arrays on a menu

Tags: jquery, arrays, list

I'm using a HTML structure similar to this

```
<ul class="top-level">
   <li><a href="#"></a>
       <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#"></a>
          </li>
       <ul>
   <li>
</ul>
```

With jQuery like this

```
$(".top-level").on("click", "a", function() {
  $(this).next("ul.dropdown").toggle(); // Show / hide the corresponding sub-menu
});
```

Except that after clicking on one link to bring down a dropdown, when I click on another top-level link to bring down another dropdown, the first dropdown doesn't disappear. Is there a way to select all other elements in .dropdown except for the one i want and ask them to hide themselves?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".top-level").on("click", "a", function() {
  var theDrop = $(this).next("ul.dropdown"); //convert dropdown in question to var
  theDropState = theDrop.is(':visible'); //record current state of dropdown
  $("ul.dropdown").hide(); //hide all dropdowns
  if(!theDropState){ theDrop.show(); } //if state was invisible, show dropdown
});
```

This method is stateless and will set up the correct conditions every time. With using toggle you risk doing things like `$('ul.dropdown').toggle();` causing all drop-downs to show at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

```
$(".top-level").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('ul.dropdown').hide(); 
  $(this).next("ul.dropdown").toggle(); // Show / hide the corresponding sub-menu
});
```

And if you click on a already opened drop down it will first hide and then appear again. to avoid that modify it like

```
$(".top-level").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).next("ul.dropdown").is('visible'))
      return;
    // as the target drop down is already visible do nothing and return      
    $('ul.dropdown').hide(); 
    $(this).next("ul.dropdown").toggle(); 
         // Show / hide the corresponding sub-menu
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can hide any visible drop down list first. Then you go ahead and display your are currently clicking.

```
$(".top-level").on("click", "a", function() {
     $('ul.dropdown').fadeOut(100); //hide any visible drop down first
     $(this).next("ul.dropdown").toggle(); // Show / hide the corresponding sub-menu
});
```

Hope that's what you want.

Comment: As you are hiding everything first. `.toggle` will always show.